# tensorflow create variable during map_fn step

Tags: python, tensorflow

is there some way to create variables in a map_fn loop like shown in the code beneath? how can I solve this error while keeping a variable in the loop? the info log does not really help me either, so am I getting any concept of tensorflow fundamentally wrong here? [tensorflow 1.14.0, python 3.6.8]

```
import tensorflow as tf


### function called in map_fn
def opt_variable(theta):
    init_theta = lambda: theta
    var_theta = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.Variable(init_theta))
    ### ... other steps which need variable type to optimize
    return tf.constant(3.)  # some return


def iterate_over_cols(theta):
    iter_cols = tf.range(5)
    map_theta = tf.map_fn(lambda x: (opt_variable(theta[x])),
iter_cols, dtype=tf.float32 )
    return map_theta


### example run
t_test = tf.convert_to_tensor([1.4, 3.1, 4.6, 6.3], dtype=tf.float32)
iterate_over_cols(t_test)
```

leads to this error:

> ValueError: Cannot use 'map_18/while/strided_slice' as input to
>   'map_18/while/Variable/Assign' because 'map_18/while/strided_slice' is
>   in a while loop. See info log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can not use nested while loops in this version, that means you can not use the output of one map_fn to the input of the other.